# Use named capturing to find out all names of named groups in a given regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I want to know if there's a named capturing group in a given regular expression, so I am going to use named capturing to find out all of the names in that expression.

Please see below code snippet:

```
std::string expr = "(?<ns>\\S+)";                // (?<ns>\S+)
boost::regex re("\\(\\?\\<(?<name>.+)\\>");      // \(\?\<(?<name>.+)\>
bool found = boost::regex_search(expr, re);      // **found is always false**
```

I also tried using following two online regex testers to verify, both of them worked and found "ns".

- https://regex101.com
- http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Why my code didn't work ? Did I misuse boost::regex ?

The version of C++ Boost library I used is 1.59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not escape the `<` and `>`.  Try this:

```
"\\(\\?<(?<name>.+)>"
```

Comment: Update: finally I use this expression "\\(\\?<(?<name>[^<>]+)>" to find out named group names.